# adjusting a div at the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the blue div at the bottom of this picture, and I'm stuck for some reason.

My CSS:

```
    .boxes {
        margin-left: 4%;
        margin-right: -4px; 
        height: 345px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .box-one{
        background-image: url("uploadir.com/u/nxa8310f");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .index-image-text {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2E3192;
        }
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="boxes img-rounded box-one grid-20">

    <h1>Pottery Painting</h1>
        <p class="index-image-text">
            Testing<br>             
        </p>

    </div>
```

It shows the little gap on both sides, but i want it all the way at the bottom of the div, and without the gap.

This is what it's showing:

https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/b4a1b72231a52f3a4977f68b76c0a7ad.png

this is what I want it to show:
https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/c66fe095c68250837b4b320c87bf72f0.png

any ideas? here's a fiddle: jsfiddle.net/kzaLx2vb/

Comment: Something like this - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLvpk22s/)?

Comment: Just give your .index-image-text class an absolute position, left/bottom/right =0px and maybe a height..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this help.

> **HTML:**

```
<div class="boxes img-rounded box-one grid-20">
        <h1>Pottery Painting</h1>
        <p class="index-image-text">Testing</p>
</div>
```

> **CSS:**

```
body {
    width: 300px;
}
.boxes {
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: -4px; 
    height: 345px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.box-one{
    background-image: url("http://uploadir.com/u/nxa8310f");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.index-image-text {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position:relative; 
    top:75%;            
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2E3192;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5q354m3h/

Answer (score 0):

A good way to achieve what you want is to give the box a relative style:

```
.box-one{
 position:relative;
}
```

and then absolutely position your index-image-text

```
.index-image-text {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kzaLx2vb/11/

CSS:

```
.boxes {
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: -4px; 
    height: 345px;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* addition code */
    padding: 0; /*change your padding from 5px to 0*/
    position: relative; /* set to relative to be the reference outter box */
    border-radius: 10px; /* rounded corner based on the reference image */
    overflow: hidden; /* to cut out for the bottom rounded corner  */
    max-width: 320px; /* this line not required*/
}

.box-one{
    background-image: url("http://uploadir.com/u/nxa8310f");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.index-image-text {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2E3192;
    /* addition code */
    margin: 0; /* override default padding value on "p" tag */
    padding-top: 10px; /* spacing based on the reference image */
    position: absolute; /* set to absolute to position within relative outter box */
    bottom: 0; /* make the inner box stick to the bottom of outter box */
    width: 100%; /* stretch the inner box to fill up outter box */
    text-align: center; /* position based on the reference image */
    font-family: verdana; /* font fammily based on the image */
}
```